# How to create Dart package to use in Android and Swift Projects?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, package

I have an application that use Flutter. In application, i am using flutter_blue_plus package to communicate ble devices. I wrote also a bluetooth service to handle packaging, encoding (AES for example) sending data. i want to make that bluetooth service(dart code) like package to use in other application like native android or iOS applications. Is there a way to make it?

Appreciated any documention, video or example code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the officials docs [Developing packages & plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)

Else check for some tutorials.